# upgraded rmbp 13 inch late 2013 to 10.9.5, now external (usb) keyboard not working

Tags: macos, usb, keyboard, macbook-pro-retina

I upgraded my retina macbook pro to 10.9.5 osx and my external keyboard is not working. I'm not 100% certain that the keyboard stopped working immediately after the upgrade or shortly afterwards.

My keyboard used to be plugged into the laptop and the mouse used to be connected to the keyboard (laptop<=keyboard<=mouse) and everything used to work perfectly. Now my mouse works when i plug it directly into the laptop (so mac's usb system isn't shot). The keyboard works when I plug that into an older windows laptop (so the keyboard isn't shot). But the keyboard+mac combo doesn't work when I plug it into either of the usb ports.

The keyboard itself is an apple keyboard!

Looking at the USB entry under system report, under USB device tree, I see this:

USB 3.0 Hi-Speed Bus
-Optical USB Mouse
-BRCM20702 Hub
--Bluetooth USB HostController
-Apple Internal Keyboard/Trackpad
USB 3.0 SuperSpeed Bus
-Internal Memory Card Reader

Any ideas??

Comment: What does it say when you do an Apple Hardware Test? See http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DavidPostill If I were able to leave a comment then I would have but a nonsensical policy restricted me to leaving an answer only.

Comment: **nonsensical policy**? If you disagree with the policy please take it up on meta.superuser.com. I suggest you read [Why is commenting everywhere restricted to those with enough reputation?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3843/why-is-commenting-everywhere-restricted-to-those-with-enough-reputation) first ;)

Comment: @TimDoyle I did the test, it showed nothing wrong! I also did pram and some other reset, still nothing. Turns out I can still call support. They told me to bring the machine in, along with my keyboard. Hopefully the store employees can solve it for me.